# Design patterns to construct an event-driven system in c++ without type erasure?

Tags: c++, generics, events

Event-driven systems are used to reduce dependencies in large systems with many-to-many object interactions of various types. As such, they aim to pass arbitrary information between arbitrary objects. This is typically done by registering event `handlers` with an `event_manager`, using type erasure in the `handler`, i.e.:

```
void handle_some_event(event *e) {/*Downcast e to an assumed appropriate type and work with it*/}
```

However, suppose we wanted to implement such a system without type erasure. It seems that certain language features, particularly generics, *should* make it possible. The `handler` registration in the `event_manager` could be templated, i.e. (loosely):

```
template<typename event_type>
void event_manager::register_handler(std::function<void(event_type)> handler) {
    // Implementation
}
```

The struggle is, what should the `//Implementation` of this function be? After receiving the handler, it needs to be *stored* in some container related to `event_type`. But in order to avoid type erasure, there would have to be a container *per* `event_type`.

One possible option is to use static containers in template classes, i.e.:

```
template<typename event_type>
class handler_container {
public:
    inline static std::vector<std::function<void(event_type)>> handlers;
};
```

The `event_manager` could store and execute handlers in the corresponding `handler_container<event_type>::handlers` container. However, this has the obvious disadvantage that there can only really be one `event_manager`, given that the containers are static and thus shared across all `event_managers`. Perhaps this is sufficient for most applications, but it's still an ugly solution.

Are there any design patterns that would allow for a cleaner solution to this problem?

Comment: You are correct. Presence of event_manager indicates some kind of bottle-neck pattern in whole logic. Dump it. Investigate Qt (that does it with code generators) or Boost.Signals2 (that does it with template meta-programming) or others like that ... rare are as naive like what you describe.

Comment: If you have a type like `event_type` then you can provide type `type_traits` for any such `event_type`s which will provide event handlers.

Comment: @marcinj This sounds promising. Could you elaborate on how you'd use `type_traits` for event handlers, perhaps in the form of an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Not a design pattern, but in theory it looks like a potential use case for [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant). You can define your event type as an alias to a `std::variant` of all possible event options, and your handlers would be C++20's [template lambdas](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/more-powerful-lambdas-with-c-20) that check for the type they want using [`constexpr if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#:%7E:text=since%20C%2B%2B17)-,Constexpr%20if,-The%20statement%20that). Finally, the code that generates the event initializes the `std::variant` with an appropriate event type and all handlers are invoked with [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit).

Use of `std::variant` might seem like a potential problem of scalability, but if the handlers are written sensibly they shouldn't break when adding more variants.

I don't know of any major project that uses this "technique", so I wouldn't jump ahead to use it in production code immediately. Also, it requires C++20 to write it without (too much) boilerplate, so it might not apply for most use cases out there. But it looks doable and doesn't require type erasure.

Comment: +1. I wasn't aware of `std::variant` or `std::visit`. But I *would* like to operate under the assumption that the number of event types could grow indefinitely. Even though variadic templates can be instantiated with any number of arguments, the code would at least be a bit messy when there are many different event types, I think.

Comment: At least the handler code would not need to be aware of the number of types, unless it would want to handle all possible cases of course. The event manager code could potentially get unwieldy, but I don't immediately see a case where it would be impossible to make it fairly clean. That said, my concern would be that given enough possible event types the compile times would most likely get unmanagable.